# How to deal with a mutable variable once it is assigned?

Tags: rust, mutable

From other questions, I figured out how to structure a complex JSON object. To get my JSON object right, I need to check if a "key" is already assigned to this `result_object`.

Since the object is now `&mut` I'm not able to use this for other operations, like in an `if` condition.

How can I deal with a circumstance like this?

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate serde_json;

fn main() {
    let my_vec = ["foo", "bar", "baz", "foobar", "barfoo"];
    let mut curr_obj = json!(null);
    {
        let mut obj_ref = &mut curr_obj;
        for i in 0..my_vec.len() {
            let name = my_vec[i];

            if curr_obj.is_null() {
                //do stuff
            }
            obj_ref = &mut { obj_ref }[name]; // note the curly braces
        }
    }
    println!("{:?}", curr_obj);
}
```

Error:

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `curr_obj` as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable
  --> src/main.rs:12:16
   |
8  |         let mut obj_ref = &mut curr_obj;
   |                                -------- mutable borrow occurs here
...
12 |             if curr_obj.is_null() {
   |                ^^^^^^^^ immutable borrow occurs here
...
17 |     }
   |     - mutable borrow ends here
```

Comment: The `json!` is more when [you need to write a json value with json syntax in your code](https://github.com/serde-rs/json#constructing-json-values). You should try to create struct matching your object, and then parsing to this struct: https://github.com/serde-rs/json#parsing-json-as-strongly-typed-data-structures and https://github.com/serde-rs/json#creating-json-by-serializing-data-structures

Comment: @FrancoisMockers - I also thought about this. But in my case I'm transforming an xml to json. Since the xml can be structured in very different ways I'm not sure how this could be represented as a struct

Comment: Can't you do  `let is_null = curr_obj.is_null();`  before borrowing it and then just use the variable?